# Menus showing up on wrong monitor with Fedora 23

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, fedora, xorg, gnome3

Hardware: Dell XPS 15 9550 (4K touchscreen) with DisplayLink box

Software: Fedora 23, displaylink driver 1.0.335, video driver xorg-x11-drv-intel-2.99.917-16.20150729

I have searched for similar issues around the web but only found an old Firefox-related Ubuntu issue on Launchpad, so here's my question.

I have two external monitors connected to a diplaylink box which is connected to my laptop. Whenever I want to use a (context) menu of an app that is running on one of the external monitors, it shows up either on the built-in laptop display (Gtk and Qt apps) or not at all (Firefox). Only Chromium menus seem to show up in the right place. I have tried turning off the built-in display in the Gnome settings but that didn't solve the problem.

Does anyone have an idea of how to configure my box in such a way that menus will show up in the right position?

Answer (score 1):

Problem is fixed by a recent software update: xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.18.3-1.fc23.x86_64

Answer (score 0):

the issue is probably with the displaylink drivers and/or compatibility with your Xorg, I have the same issue on-and-off with different versions of the driver and Xorg.

Currently I run Xorg 1.18.1 and displaylink drivers 1.0.335 and I don't have the issue. (but IIRC 1.18.0 had issues, and the last 1.16 I had didn't)

ps: note that I'm not running fedora, so I don't know which versions of Xorg are available for it.

Comment: Seems to match fc23's xorg version: xorg-x11-server-common-1.18.0-2.fc23.x86_64

Comment: @reinouts maybe try backporting 1.18.1 from fc24
I saw this in the changelog on koji:
* Mon Feb 15 2016 Dave Airlie <airlied@redhat.com> 1.18.1-2 - fix issues with reverse prime and present.

And since the displaylink uses reverse prime, this should help.
Or open a bug asking te provide 1.18.1 in fc23 too.
[source] http://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=735963

Comment: thanks for the info; I've added this request to https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1254280 .